# How to detect text node in element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi I have the following issue:

I need to detect if certain element has child text node in it, but excluding leading and trailing spaces, carriage return, tabs and line feeds. Any "empty" space doesn't count for text.

I found this function **normalize-space()** and it partly work for me. But if the text node is placed after nested element the function doesn't find it. For example:

```
<list>
   <list-item/>
   This is the text node
</list>
```

So when the current context match the `<list>` element `<xsl:value-of select="noramalize-space(text())"/>` returns empty string. But it should return "**This is the text node**" isn't it?

Here is the code I am experimenting on:

**.xml**:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <empty-element>
            <nested-empty-element/>
        </empty-element>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <list>
            <list-itme>
                <bullet>This is bullet</bullet>
            </list-itme>
        This is the text node
        </list>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**.xsl**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(text())">
            <para>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </para>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After the transformation I get this result:

```
<root>
    <para>Empire Burlesque</para>
    <para>Bob Dylan</para>
</root>
```

And the question is: Why I am not getting this result?:

```
<root>
    <para>Empire Burlesque</para>
    <para>This is the text node</para>
    <para>Bob Dylan</para>
</root>
```

Why `list` element is not processed, It has text node as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is a white-space text node under `list` before `list-itme` (I've added a comment to show where. Technically you would then have two white space nodes for the below XML. One before the comment, and one after)

```
    <list>        <!-- Whitespace text node here -->
        <list-itme>
            <bullet>This is bullet</bullet>
        </list-itme>
    This is the text node
    </list>
```

If you want to ignore these whitespace nodes, then you can use the `xsl:strip-space` command to ignore them

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(text())">
            <para>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
            </para>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, the same result can be achieved by testing for any text node where normalize-space is not empty (Your current expression is normalising the first text node)

```
 <xsl:if test="text()[normalize-space()]">
```

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="text()[normalize-space()]">
            <para>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text()[normalize-space()])"/>
            </para>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim C for the fast reply. Your code works for me. One thing left vague for me. Could you pleas explain what does this `[normalize-space()]` do into the second example? Shouldn't `normalize-space()` strip these spaces?

Comment: If you have not used `xsl:strip-spaces` then if you just do `normalize-space(text())` then this normalises the spaces of the first text node, which in your example is a whitespace-only text node. As there are multiple text nodes,  adding a condition of `[normalize-space()]` will select the first text node which is non-empty. The condition `[normalize-space()]` itself does not normalizes space. It is just a selecter.